# ViewController Storyboard ID from a variable

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, segue, viewcontroller

How can I set in the Storyboard a `ViewController Storyboard ID` from a `variable` in a `struct swift file`?

I don't want to write down the Storyboard ID of a VC from the Identity Inspector > Identity > StoryboardID hardcoded. I want it to be in a variable in a struct swift file where I can access it and also set it/change it from there.

Comment: I don't answer substituting a hardcoded string inside a swift file with a variable , I mean this is the only way to dynamically load a vc , BTW your request doesn't exist you may try it in Android or any other platform as there is no mental use case for it

Answer (score 0):

From Apple docs. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistoryboard/1616214-instantiateviewcontroller

> **An identifier string that uniquely identifies the view controller in
>   the storyboard file.** You set the identifier for a given view
>   controller in Interface Builder when configuring the storyboard file.
>   **This identifier is not a property of the view controller object itself**
>   and is used only by the storyboard file to locate the view controller.
>
> If the specified identifier does not exist (or is nil) in the
>   storyboard file, this method raises an exception.

As `storyboardID` is not the property of the ViewController or some other class we may not access this property.